# axios error Namespace 'axios' not found ts(2503)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

You get the following error in axios.AxiosResponse.
How can I fix it?

error
Namespace 'axios' not found ts(2503)

```
import axios from 'axios';

Axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response: axios.AxiosResponse) => {
    return Promise.resolve(response.data);
  },
  (error) => errorHandler(error),
);
```

Comment: cant understand `Axios` and `(response: axios.AxiosResponse)` in your code. here is the `axios interceptors` link https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#interceptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `AxiosResponse` from the `axios` package:

```
import axios, {AxiosResponse} from 'axios';

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response: AxiosResponse) => {
    return Promise.resolve(response.data);
  },
  (error) => errorHandler(error),
);
```